# PDF Reader for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian

I am looking for a free pdf reader for my raspberry pi to use in fullscreen and display on a monitor.

Thanks.
Dimitri

Comment: The answer will depend on what operating system are you running, i.e. are you running Raspbian? But will probably boil down to a [Here let me google that for you](https://googlethatforyou.com?q=free%20pdf%20viewer%20raspbian)  type answer.

Comment: your question is not about the RPi ... it is a linux question

Answer (score 4):

Raspbian includes the `qpdfview` PDF viewer.

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspbian-update-june-2018/

This has Full Screen option and also Presentation mode

Comment: upvoted because raspbian is targeted.

Answer (score 3):

I use Pi's headless for the most part, but my preferred PDF viewer on GNU/Linux generally is [`okular`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okular).  It's fairly intuitive and feature rich (in some ways I prefer it to Adobe Acrobat).

It's under the [KDE](https://kde.org/) umbrella, meaning it uses the Qt widget library.  KDE is a complete desktop environment, alternative to the LXDE derived one used by default in Raspbian.  However, you don't need to use it to use okular.<sup>1</sup>

It is available in Raspbian:

```
apt install okular
```

If you don't have any Qt based apps installed previously, this may have a hefty dependency list.  On my x64 machine here an instance is reasonably light memory wise for a complex GUI app with a resident size of ~55 MB viewing a 500 page pdf format ebook.

From https://okular.kde.org/:

> Okular is a universal document viewer developed by KDE. Okular works on multiple platforms, including but not limited to Linux, Windows, macOS, *BSD, etc.
>
> The last stable release is Okular 1.9.
>
> Okular combines the excellent functionalities with the versatility of supporting different kind of documents, like PDF, Postscript, DjVu, CHM, XPS, ePub and others.

---

1. KDE is quite a bit snazzier than LXDE, but I think it may be a bit much for most Raspberry Pis.

Answer (score 2):

Using this debian package for example,

`sudo apt-get install xpdf`

[image]

Use `rigth click for fullscreen option` or use this command line `xpdf -fullscreen file.pdf`

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> xpdf [options] [PDF-file [:page | +dest]] ...
>
> xpdf [options] -remote remote-name [command ...]
>
> xpdf [options] -open [PDF-file]

You can search package with :

`sudo apt-cache search pdf viewer`

Comment: Raspbian replaced "Xpdf with a program called qpdfView, which is a much-improved PDF viewer".

Answer (score 1):

Use your favorite web browser.

Chromium and Firefox are easily usable on a Raspberry Pi.

Chromium is already built into the Raspbian distribution, and can display PDF's.

Press "F11" on your keyboard to go full screen.